# How not to show Universal Access menu Icon in task bar in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: icons

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in my assembled computer with 32" TV as monitor.

I work little away from this TV.
so I adjusted in Fonts tab "Scaling Factor" in Gnome Tweaks.
This will activate "Universal Access" "Large Text" to on and then a icon (circle with human) is shown adjacent to date. How to disable this icon ?[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: as of Ubuntu 19.10, the "Remove Accessibility" extension is not anymore included in the Ubuntu Software Center. Despite not being updated for some time, the extension can be installed from the Gnome Extensions website and also works in 19.10. See second answer.

Open Ubuntu Software Center, click search sign at the right upper corner of the window and type in the search field "Gnome shell extensions Remove Accessibility" phrase. You'll see the "Remove Accessibility" Gnome shell extension.
[image]
Install the extension and "Universal Access" icon has to disappear.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dedicated GNOME extension for this: [Remove Accessibility](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/112/remove-accesibility/)

Comment: Still works in Focal 20.04

Answer (score 0):

The extension below worked for me on Ubuntu 20.10 with GNOME Shell 3.38.2 :

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2398/hide-universal-access/