# Terminal based text scaling / How to get rid of accessibility icon in top bar?

Tags: 20.04, gui, text, accessibility

Looking for a solution to use text scaling without using the accessibility feature I came across [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/1273884/897783). However, this also uses accessibility, but I want no accessibility icon. How may I either scale text without using accessibility or get rid of the icon while using?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1053221/739431

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How not to show Universal Access menu Icon in task bar in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053221/how-not-to-show-universal-access-menu-icon-in-task-bar-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @vanadium Works, thx! Hard to find though, but the duplicate should make it better.